# Regex matching a string but should give only one/more digits as output from the line

Tags: regex

I am writing a regex to find a string/line out of a large text file but need to get only few numeric values against the matched string.

Here is the example:

If below is the line that I am looking for in the large text file

```
 http.add.user.success 50.0 50 50 0.0 1
```

But all i need, regex to return is the first numeric value in this line which is `50.0`

I tried

```
^http.add.user.success\s*[0-9]+\.[0-9]
```

but this is giving me output as below

```
http.add.user.success 50.0
```

While I want output only `50.0`

Comment: What are you using to perform the regex search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**awk** can also do it:

```
awk '/^http.add.user.success /{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **sed** on the command line

```
sed s'/^http\.add\.user\.success \([0-9]\+.[0-9]\).*$/\1/' test.txt
```